# Is there a way to sort pandas columns by intersections with rows?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rows, columnsorting

I have a pandas table with rows and columns and data in only some intersections between the rows and columns. See below:

```
     col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
row1  1
row2               1    1
row3  1     
row4                    1     1
row5        1
```

I want to sort columns, so that the columns that have 1 in intersection with row 1 would go first, columns with intersection with row 2 second and so on. Like below:

```
     col1  col3  col4  col5  col2
row1  1
row2        1      1    
row3  1     
row4               1     1
row5                          1
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those empty cell are `Nan`, you can just use `idxmax()` on `notnull()`:

```
orders = df.notnull().agg(['any', 'idxmax']).T
col_orders = orders.sort_values(['any', 'idxmax'],
                                ascending=[False, True]).index


df[col_orders]
```

Output:

```
      col1  col3  col4  col5  col2
row1   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
row2   NaN   1.0   1.0   NaN   NaN
row3   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
row4   NaN   NaN   1.0   1.0   NaN
row5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0
```

Comment: @joaquin It is needed, as the `max` in each column can appear in later rows. Think what happens if `col1` is `1 nan 3 nan nan`.

Comment: I also realized I have a column with all rows filled with NaN. Somehow when I run what you wrote I get this column to be second, not last. Do you know how I can avoid this? Or should I edit the question for this?

Comment: @danvoronov thanks, that's obviously an interesting edge case. See update.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks, it did not work for my data set giving KeyError: 'any'.
But worked after adding axis 1 and transposing:
`col_orders = orders.sort_values(['any', 'idxmax'], axis=1).T.index`

Comment: @danvoronov Thanks. also see my last update for the correct `sort_values`

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks, I have accepted your answer, but I think if some rows have same number of intersections, then there is a mistake in column re-ordering, because idxmax looks at maximum counts and not at the first intersection, given the row order, I think.